# How to drop extra input for scanf of %20s

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am doing an assignment for an intro to c class so my knowledge is still pretty minimal, please be nice.  I have

```
scanf(" %20s", contact.name");
printf("Do you want to enter a middle name?");
scanf(" %c", doYouWant");
```

If the first scanf is more than 20 characters the characters will be the input for the next scanf.  If I use %s then it will accept the entire line but will be longer then the memory allocated.

I need to get the first input and store in my struct then ask the next question. How do properly avoid having characters 21+ being used as input to the next question while limiting it to 20 characters.

Comment: Just use %s and get as many as they type, then truncate to 20.

Comment: If the input was too long, you can't proceed anyway. Use an input string with length 25. `scanf("%24s", inpstring);` If the string entered is longer than `20` then abort. Otherwise `strcpy(contact.name, inpstring);` Note, `contact.name` struct member should be defined as `char name[21];`

Comment: I should have mentioned we haven't been taught the string functions yet and are expected to not use them for this assignment.  This is what in was thinking to do but was told I couldn't here.  Thanks for the info, at least I know I had the right idea even if I can't use it yet.  Using %20s%*s has done the trick.

Comment: Nope, please see comment under your answer.

Comment: Your biggest problem will be the `%s` *format specifier* **reading up to the first whitespace** leaving any additional characters, and the trailing `"\n"` in the input buffer. Your next call to `" %c"` will only disregard leading whitespace by virtue of the initial space in the *format string*, but not any other characters. You should empty-`stdin` before the next `scanf` call, e.g. `for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()} {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to drop the extra input which wasn't consumed by `scanf`, one way of doing it is to read and discard the extra input using a loop, like this:

```
scanf(" %20s", contact.name);
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)  // <=== This loop read the extra input characters and discard them
    /* discard the character */;
printf("Do you want to enter a middle name?");
.....
.....
```

The body of the loop is empty; we do nothing with the characters we're reading, thus discarding them.

Comment: Works perfectly.  So simple and effective.  Thank you

Comment: Note that the space in `" %20s"` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fgets` to read in a complete line (probably longer than the length of the name you accept), truncate it to appropriate length and copy it to the destination:

```
int main(){
    char buffer[500];
    if (fgets(buffer,500,stdin)) {  // reads in a line including newline character
        buffer[20]='\0'; // truncate to at most 20 characters (note: requires an array/memory of length 21)
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")]='\0';  // cut of the newline character (if any)
        strcpy(contact.name, buffer);
        printf("Do you want to enter a middle name?");
        scanf(" %c", &doYouWant);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The blank in `" %c"` is necessary if you like to accept " y" as input as well; note, however, that the new line has already been consumed by `fgets`...

Comment: Mixing `fgets()` and `scanf(" %c"...)` leads to troubles.  Perhaps not wit the simple code, yet in general.  Best to just use `fgets()` for user input.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it for an hour but I have it now.

```
scanf(" %30s%*s", name.firstName);
```

The %*s swallows (sends to the bit bucket I am guessing) the extra characters if I understood it right.

Comment: But if there were no extra characters? It sits and waits.

Comment: I got stuck testing 31+ characters and forgot to test less. You are right.